# Aurelia: Using index value to increment array value in input binding

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

I am trying to increment an array value inside a value.bind directive so that, in this example, three rows are created, incrementing the array number:

```
<tr repeat.for="i of 3">
    <td><input  type="text" value.bind="GS.qData.estate[**${$index}**].name"></td>
**strong text**</tr>
```

I have tried several permutations ( {$i}, etc ), but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried just using `i`? `value.bind="GS.qData.estate[i].name"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Further research seems to show that the repeater won't do this, so I have other solutions.
Thanks for the reply.